# Getting Control Properties by Function VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, combobox, controls

I am trying to create a function that will create some properties for a control (in this case, a combobox).  However, the receiving control does not get the value properties from the function.

Here is the function that creates the property.

```
Public Function getComboboxProperties(ByVal dt As DataTable) As
ComboBox
    Try
        Dim ctrlCombobox As New ComboBox
        ctrlCombobox.BindingContext = New BindingContext
        ctrlCombobox.DataSource = dt
        ctrlCombobox.ValueMember = "ID"
        ctrlCombobox.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPTION"
        getComboboxProperties = ctrlCombobox
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try End Function
```

new value is passed by:

```
cmbCompanyStatus = clsCommon.getComboboxProperties(dtStatus)
```

When I open the form, combobox cmbCompanyStatus does not pick up the datasource and displays nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!.

Comment: Might seem like a stupid question, but *where* is `cmbCompanyStatus` assigned?

Comment: Maybe edit the question to make what you're asking slightly clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the likely cause is an exception being thrown somewhere in your assignments. The statements

```
Return Nothing
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
```

are the wrong way round; the function will return without displaying the message box.

Also,

```
getComboboxProperties = ctrlCombobox
```

is a rather old-fashioned way of returning a value; in VB.Net one would prefer

```
Return ctrlCombobox
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, you appear to be missing the following:

```
' Snip
    ctrlCombobox.DataSource = dt
    ctrlCombobox.ValueMember = "ID"
    ctrlCombobox.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPTION"
    ctrlCombobox.DataBind() ' <-------------------- This line here
    getComboboxProperties = ctrlCombobox
```